# Couchbase unable to access password protected bucket

Tags: java, couchbase

I run a couchbase server on a remote machine that has a bucket called "targeting-dev" on it. Until today, the bucket did not have any password and  I was able to access and query that bucket to my heart's content.
Today, I set a password on the bucket using

```
./couchbase-cli bucket-edit -c host.ip:8091 -u Admin -p password --bucket=targeting-dev --bucket-password=p4$$w0rd
```

Since then, stuff seems weird. I still can run queries using "cbq":

```
./cbq -engine="http://targeting-dev:p4$$w0rd@46.137.95.41:8093/"
```

And all the queries execute OK with the password and Authentication fails without.

When I try to run queries in a web browser as follows (which worked in pre-password times):

```
http://host.ip:8092/targeting-dev/_design/dev_targeting-dev/_view/user_count
```

That now pops-up authentication window and I tried using "targeting-dev/p4$$w0rd" for username and password, but that does not let me log in.

Finally, I have the following Java code:

```
public AbstractRepository(final Database config) {
    this.config = config;
    this.cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(config.getNodes());
    this.bucket = cluster.openBucket(bucket, password);
}
```

where bucket="targeting-dev" and password="p4$$w0rd" as confirmed in the debugger.

That now throws the following exception:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "targeting-dev" do not match.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
```

I know, that's a long question with many variations of accessing one bucket, but could anyone please enlighten me on where am I going wrong in case of the Java application and the web browser access?

Could the key be the wrong port number I use (for the web browser) - I tried several combination but none works?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found the culprit - it looks like Couchbase doesn't like "$" in passwords. Setting the password to "p455w0rd" seem to have fixed the issue for both the web browser and Java app. All is working now.

Thinking about it: the browser would encode `$` and whatever the server receives as a result of such encoding doesn't match the expected password.
Perhaps you better steer clear off special characters that get HTTP encoded if  you plan to test your queries using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

In Couchbase Server 5.0, role-based access controls were introduced. You must now create a user with a name that matches the bucket name and use that user's password when opening the bucket. The user must have a role with access rights to the bucket.

Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create();
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("hero", "password");

In the above example your bucket name is hero and you should have a user created under security section with name "hero". You will not see any option while creating bucket to add password.

[Couchbase Bucket authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169384/couchbase-bucket-authentication-error)